# What is the proper setup for "anacron"? (Ubuntu 9.10, 10.04)

Tags: ubuntu, log-files, cron, init.d

I am running Ubuntu 9.10 and 10.04 on MediaTemple (ve) servers.

On both of them, the **anacron** setup is broken, ... and they have been broken since I first installed Ubuntu.  It has only come to my attention recently, when I realize my log files were not rotating.

I am hoping someone who has anacron working can help diagnose the problem and suggest a fix.

Here is **/etc/cron.d/anacron** ...
This part works correctly:  Every morning at 7:30am, **cron** executes this command to start up anacron.

```
# /etc/cron.d/anacron: crontab entries for the anacron package

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

30 7    * * *   root    test -x /etc/init.d/anacron && /etc/init.d/anacron start >/dev/null
```

The problem is that **/etc/init.d/anacron start** fails:

```
# /etc/init.d/anacron start >/dev/null
start: Unknown job: anacron
```

Notice that /etc/init.d/anacron is a symbolic link to /lib/init/upstart-job:

```
# ls -l /etc/init.d/anacron
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 Jan 12  2010 /etc/init.d/anacron -> /lib/init/upstart-job
```

Now I am stumped.  Anyone have any suggestions how to fix this?

Take a look in **/var/log** and see if your log files are being rotated (as opposed to growing indefinitely).  If they **are** being rotated, then you probably have a working **anacron**, so please check your setup and let me know how it differs from mine.

Thanks in advance, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upstart actually uses config files in `/etc/init` for each service, not `/etc/init.d`.  I assume the /etc/init.d links are there to preserve compatibility with sysvinit.  Here's the [upstart getting started guide](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/getting-started.html) which explains this.

I don't have an ubuntu system so I can't check the contents of `/etc/init/anacron.conf`, but I suspect from gooling it might just be `exec anacron -s`.  Check in `/etc/init.removed/` and see if there is an anacron.conf there that was removed by some upgrade process.  You might be able to reinstall anacron to fix this as well.

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful.  I would up-vote your answer, but I need reputation 15 for that.  If you up-vote my question, maybe I can up-vote your answer :-)

Comment: I found a version of "anacron.conf" in /etc/init.removed, so I moved it back into /etc/init/

Comment: If my answer worked, please accept it.  You can do that with any amount of reputation, separate from upvoting it.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 10.04 /etc/cron.d/anacron:

```
# /etc/cron.d/anacron: crontab entries for the anacron package

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

#30 7    * * *   root   test -x /etc/init.d/anacron && /usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d anacron start >/dev/null
30 7    * * *   root    start -q anacron || :
```

/etc/init.d/anacron start:

```
# /etc/init.d/anacron start
Rather than invoking init scripts through /etc/init.d, use the service(8)
utility, e.g. service anacron start

Since the script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an
Upstart job, you may also use the start(8) utility, e.g. start anacron

# ls -al /etc/init.d/anacron 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 2011-01-10 19:05 /etc/init.d/anacron -> /lib/init/upstart-job
anacron start/running, process 5446
```

/etc/cron.daily/logrotate can be started without anacron, when /usr/sbin/anacron not existed(/etc/crontab):

```
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
```

Comment: The source of my trouble was a missing /etc/init/anacron.conf, which I was able to recover from /etc/init.removed/anacron.conf

Comment: After restoring /etc/init/anacron.conf the command "/etc/init.d/anacron start" works, ... though it does suggest using "start anacron" instead.  But both seem to work.